# passportjs and backbone: authenticating users

Tags: backbone.js, express, passport.js

Currently I been using a chrome app called Postman to test my services from nodejs/express/passportjs.

Currently I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I should grab the user info and authenticate it with backbone.

I would try to authenticate the user like so:

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000/login", { username: "joe", password: "pass" })
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  //try to pull a service that's protected by passport
})
.fail(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Which is not working at all when it's successful. Its giving the 500 error I set for when someone isn't logged in.

Any particular direction I should be going in to manage authentication with passportjs in backbone?

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error means some part of the code in the server is not working properly. 
You can send the logged in user from express using passport. You can follow the following example.

```
var app = express();
var login = require('./routes/login');
app.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',  
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true }), 
    login.login);
```

where your login.js file may look like this

```
exports.login = function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
}
```

the authenticate process of passport populates user variable in request (req) with the logged in user.

Please note, you have to use cookie parser and session of express to make the passport session working. e.g.,

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
```

your local authentication may look like the following (say you have a function that finds user by username (findByUsername)).

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {

      // Find the user by username.  If there is no user with the given
      // username, or the password is not correct, set the user to `false` to
      // indicate failure and set a flash message.  Otherwise, return the
      // authenticated `user`.
      findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
        if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
));
```